# Если в строке отсутствует символа

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Есть такая функция, нужно, чтобы в input было 16 символов и отсутствовал символ '_'.
Если оба условия истины, то $(this).removeClass('empty_field');

Вот функция:

```
function checkPhone(){
    form.find('#user_phone').each(function(){
        if(($(this).val().length == '16') && (!$(this).val().indexOf('___')+1)){

           $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
        } 
        else {
         $(this).addClass('empty_field');
        }
     });
}
```

Вроде все правильно, но что-то не работает(
Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: Начнем  стого, что indexOf('___') ищет несколько подчеркиваний подряд а не один. Это раз.

Comment: Забыты скобки после отрицания, это два. То есть сейчас ваше условие складывает true/false которое возвращает выражение !$(this).val().indexOf('___') с числом 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынеси в отдельную переменную (!$(this).val().indexOf('___')+1) и смотри что возвращает.

Да и ищет то не одно подчеркивание, а 3

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, задачу решил вот так:

```
function checkPhone(){
   var u_phone = $('#user_phone');
     if ( (u_phone.val().indexOf("_") != -1) || u_phone.val() == '' ){
      u_phone.addClass('empty_field');
      }
     else {
      u_phone.removeClass('empty_field');
  }
};
```